# 3d model become flat (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, flat

i want to ask about my 3D model. i create 3D model from blender, and i export it in fbx format. then i import it to my unity project, but when i drag it to my scene i got my 3D model flat. can you help me what should i do?

this the 3d model before i add animation, and i export to obj format
[image: this the 3d model before i add animation, and i export to obj format]

and this 3d model, after i add animation (in blender), then export it to fbx format

[image: 3d model flat]

can anyone help me?

Comment: have a look at the official [unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) site

Comment: What happens if you delete animations and export in fix format? Are scale values involved in the animations in Blender?

Comment: i try to scale my object in blender. to (1,1,1) but it become wired. how to setting scale to (1,1,1) so that i have form my right object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the import settings on the mesh, in Unity, and see if the scaling is right.  Also check to make sure your export settings from Blender were correct, for the scaling.  If that doesn't work, or you don't know what to do with those settings to fix it, I might suggest watching some tutorials on exporting/importing meshes from Blender to Unity.  You might try starting [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqHM0JkkuMs)